# how to share the current url to facebook in laravel?

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5

I want to share the current URL of my website to the facebook , so i used facebook's sharer.php. Here is my share.php file which shows icons and link to the sharer.php

```
<div class="social-buttons">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ urlencode($url) }}"
       target="_blank">
       <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

I am passing the url to the ($url) from my page through the code

```
<?php

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

?>
@include('share',['url' => 'www.google.com'])
```

This particular webpage i am sharing the URL from usually generate dynamic URL. So I change the code to

```
@include('share',['url' => 'Request::url()'])
```

so that i can share the dynamically created URL. The problem here is When i put `www.google.com` in place of url the POP UP box works fine and open up the facebook share. But when i use `['url' => 'Request::url()'])` the pop up box opens and close quickly , i tried to see the url and it was something like error. How do i fix this? is there any drawback in this approach ?

Here is the script code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var popupSize = {
        width: 780,
        height: 550
    };

    $(document).on('click', '.social-buttons > a', function(e){

        var
            verticalPos = Math.floor(($(window).width() - popupSize.width) / 2),
            horisontalPos = Math.floor(($(window).height() - popupSize.height) / 2);

        var popup = window.open($(this).prop('href'), 'social',
            'width='+popupSize.width+',height='+popupSize.height+
            ',left='+verticalPos+',top='+horisontalPos+
            ',location=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');

        if (popup) {
            popup.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide sharer.php file and controller

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
@include('share',['url' => 'Request::url()'])
```

you're passing a string **Request::url()** as the value, not the URL.

Replace that line with:

```
@include('share',['url' => Request::url()])
```

Comment: yes it works now , but facing one more issue , when i pass google.com , it works like a charm , but when i pass the current url (localhost), its says something went wrong. I am testing on localhost. is localhost causing a problem ?

Comment: Check the generated HTML and see if the URL is correct. I had some problems on localhost as for some reason the protocol (http/https) was missing from the URL.

Comment: Facebook will make a request to the URL you are sharing, to get the relevant Open Graph meta data. Of course that doesn’t work on localhost. It needs to be reachable from the outside.

Comment: That's true, so just make sure that generated URL is correct in the HTML and then test it somewhere where Facebook can access it